# Multiple custom-set-faces and custom-set-variables in .emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

When I customize a face through the `M-x customize-face` menu and save the changes to disk, Emacs adds automatically generated code to my `.emacs` file  that looks like this:

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
; 
;; SOME CODE
; 
)
```

where `SOME CODE` is something like:

```
 '(diredp-dir-priv ((t (:foreground "cyan"))))
```

Now, say that I want to **manually** make changes to `SOME CODE`, and perhaps add more code to modify other faces. Would it be smart to keep those changes under the `custom-set-faces` block? Or should I move that to a different block (to avoid Emacs from getting confused)

Also, would Emacs get confused I have **multiple**  `(custom-set-faces ... )` blocks? (same question for `(custom-set-variables ...)`

Answer (score 4):

If you are manually adding custom faces, keep it in custom-set-faces.

As for having multiple `(custom-set-faces ... )` or `(custom-set-variables ... )` lists, I have just tested this (in Emacs 23.1). They do work - Emacs will process all lists - however, if you then use `M-x customize-face` to add a new custom face (similarly for a variable) and save it for future sessions, Emacs will combine all the lists into one. So, you should probably only keep the one.