# Emacs lisp. Split custom-set-variables in multiple custom-set-variables

Tags: emacs

I have read this: [Multiple custom-set-faces and custom-set-variables in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867556/multiple-custom-set-faces-and-custom-set-variables-in-emacs)

An answer is:

> If you are manually adding custom faces, keep it in custom-set-faces.
>
> As for having multiple (custom-set-faces ... ) or (custom-set-variables ... ) lists, I have just tested this (in Emacs 23.1). They do work - Emacs will process all lists - however, if you then use M-x customize-face to add a new custom face (similarly for a variable) and save it for future sessions, Emacs will combine all the lists into one. So, you should probably only keep the one.

I would like to know if there is any way to split a `custom-set-variables` call into smaller calls. Example: I would line to split this

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (solarized-dark)))
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("8aebf25556399b58091e533e455dd50a6a9cba958cc4ebb0aab175863c25b9a4" default)))
 '(package-archives
   (quote
    (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (solarized-theme)))
)
```

into

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (solarized-dark)))
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("8aebf25556399b58091e533e455dd50a6a9cba958cc4ebb0aab175863c25b9a4" default))))

(custom-set-variables
 '(package-archives
   (quote
    (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (solarized-theme)))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are really asking.

***You*** can use `custom-set-variables` anywhere and *as many times as you want*.

However, if you *also* expect/want ***Customize*** to write to your `custom-file` (or your init file, if you do not have a `custom-file`) then what the other SO post told you holds true. When *Customize* writes to your file it coalesces the calls to `custom-set-variables`.

It is a *bad* idea to mix your own calls to `custom-set-variables` with Customize's writing of such code.

Keep your code separate from what Customize writes. That's the whole point of using a separate `custom-file`: to give Customize a separate place to play, so it doesn't mess with your code.

Comment: So... Should I keep customize by emacs in init.el and other setup in my configuration file?

Comment: I don't know what your "configuration file" is. I recommend that you define variable `custom-file` to point to a file that you want to give entirely to Customize - do not hand-code in it. Your own code can go anywhere you like: `init.el` or anywhere else (that gets loaded from your init file).

Comment: Do you refer to
`(setq custom-file "~/.emacs-custom.el")
     (load custom-file)`
?

Comment: Yes, set variable `custom-file` and then, at some point in your init file that makes sense to you, load that file.

Comment: Okk. Thank you very much!